# In which programming language this code snippet is written?

Tags: cnc

The code is written in 1999 and controls a CNC machine. If the code snippet is not adequate to determine the language i can upload the entire file. This is the code segment:

```
BEGIN CONDITION +S_P0_PRES AND +N_P0__PNLTST ON EXCEPTION BEGIN
    SET N_P0_STB OFF
    SET N_P0_KEY(*) TO BITS(0)
    SET N_P0_LTS(*) TO BITS(0)
    SET ..KEY_PLS(*) TO BITS(0)
    SET S_P0_KEY_PLS(*) TO BITS(0)
    SET S_NCX0_FLEDS(*) TO BITS(0)
    IF
    :-S_P0_PRES: BEGIN
    SET N_P0_ACT OFF
    RETURN
    END
    END IF
    WAIT +N_P0__PNLTST OR -S_P0_PRES
    END
    IF
    :+N_P0_STB: BEGIN
    LET ..KEY_INX = 0
    REPEAT WHILE [INT(..KEY_PLS(*)) <> 0]
    IF
    :+..KEY_PLS(..KEY_INX): BEGIN
    IF
    :[..KEY_NUM(..KEY_INX) < 128]: BEGIN
    IF
    :-..KEY_ISF(..KEY_INX): SET N_P0_KEY(..KEY_NUM(..KEY_INX)) OFF
    :+..KEY_ISF(..KEY_INX): SET .P0_NCX_FUN(..KEY_NUM(..KEY_INX)) OFF
    END IF
    START N_P0__NCXKEY
    END
    :[..KEY_NUM(..KEY_INX) < LAST(N_P0_KEY(*)) + 1]: BEGIN
    SET N_P0_KEY(..KEY_NUM(..KEY_INX)) OFF
    START N_P0__MAIKEY
    END
    :[..KEY_NUM(..KEY_INX) < LAST(.P0_NCX_FUN(*)) + 1]: BEGIN
    SET .P0_NCX_FUN(..KEY_NUM(..KEY_INX) - (LAST(N_P0_KEY(*)) - 127)) OFF
    START N_P0__FKEY
    END
    END IF
```

Comment: Gotta love the SO community: downvotes without explanation? Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(programming_language)).